# Error while installing Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, installation

I am trying to install eclipse IDE (Java for developers) , but facing the below error during the installation.

I have enough space in the system drive.

In past i have installed and uninstalled the eclipse IDE. So is this giving me any problem to re-install?

> 10:50:59] **ERROR**: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf code=1002 Unable
>   to read repository at
>   http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/201612211000/content.xml.xz.
>   org.apache.http.TruncatedChunkException: Truncated chunk ( expected
>   size: 8096; actual size: 7189)   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:183)
>   at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.http.client.entity.LazyDecompressingInputStream.read(LazyDecompressingInputStream.java:74)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:137)
>   at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer$1.performFileTransfer(AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:178)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.FileTransferJob.run(FileTransferJob.java:74)
>   at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
>
> [2017-01-16 10:50:59]  [2017-01-16 10:51:04] Executing bootstrap tasks
>   [2017-01-16 10:51:04] Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_111-b14
>   [2017-01-16 10:51:04] Product
>   org.eclipse.products.epp.package.java.neon [2017-01-16 10:51:04]
>   Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup 1.6.0.v20161125-0947, build=2790,
>   branch=33010448bcf5775ec23e485876cbb07a0340b9b5 [2017-01-16 10:51:04]
>   Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.core 1.6.0.v20161128-0928, build=2790,
>   branch=33010448bcf5775ec23e485876cbb07a0340b9b5 [2017-01-16 10:51:04]
>   Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2 1.6.0.v20161019-0656, build=2790,
>   branch=33010448bcf5775ec23e485876cbb07a0340b9b5 [2017-01-16 10:51:04]
>   Performing P2 Director (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (Neon))
>   [2017-01-16 10:51:04] Offline = false [2017-01-16 10:51:04] Mirrors =
>   true [2017-01-16 10:51:04] Resolving 23 requirements from 3
>   repositories to C:\personaldev\eclipse [2017-01-16 10:51:04]
>   Requirement epp.package.java [4.6.0,4.7.0) [2017-01-16 10:51:04]
>   Requirement org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.6.0,4.7.0)
>   [2017-01-16 10:51:04] Requirement org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group
>   [4.6.0,4.7.0) [2017-01-16 10:51:04] Requirement
>   org.eclipse.buildship.feature.group [2017-01-16 10:51:04] Requirement
>   org.eclipse.egit.feature.group [2017-01-16 10:51:04] Requirement
>   org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group [2017-01-16 10:51:04] Requirement
>   org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group [2017-01-16 10:51:04] Requirement
>   org.eclipse.jgit.feature.group [2017-01-16 10:51:04] Requirement
>   org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group [2017-01-16 10:51:04]
>   Requirement org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group [2017-01-16
>   10:51:04] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla_feature.feature.group
>   [2017-01-16 10:51:04] Requirement
>   org.eclipse.mylyn.context_feature.feature.group [2017-01-16 10:51:04]
>   Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.git.feature.group [2017-01-16 10:51:04]
>   Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.hudson.feature.group [2017-01-16
>   10:51:04] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.ide_feature.feature.group
>   [2017-01-16 10:51:04] Requirement
>   org.eclipse.mylyn.java_feature.feature.group [2017-01-16 10:51:04]
>   Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature.feature.group
>   [2017-01-16 10:51:04] Requirement
>   org.eclipse.mylyn_feature.feature.group [2017-01-16 10:51:04]
>   Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.mylyn.rcp.feature.feature.group
>   [2017-01-16 10:51:04] Requirement
>   org.eclipse.recommenders.rcp.feature.feature.group [2017-01-16
>   10:51:04] Requirement
>   org.eclipse.recommenders.snipmatch.rcp.feature.feature.group
>   [2017-01-16 10:51:04] Requirement
>   org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group [2017-01-16 10:51:04]
>   Requirement org.eclipse.oomph.setup.feature.group [2017-01-16
>   10:51:04] Repository
>   http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/neon [2017-01-16
>   10:51:04] Repository
>   http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/201612211000 [2017-01-16
>   10:51:04] Repository
>   http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest [2017-01-16
>   10:54:14] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf code=1002 Unable
>   to read repository at
>   http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/201612211000/content.xml.xz.
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out   at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)   at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:160)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:84)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.read(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:206)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:174)
>   at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.http.client.entity.LazyDecompressingInputStream.read(LazyDecompressingInputStream.java:74)
>   at
>   org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:137)
>   at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer$1.performFileTransfer(AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:178)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.FileTransferJob.run(FileTransferJob.java:74)
>   at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
>
> [2017-01-16 10:54:14]

Comment: Are you using the online installer? Try to download the whole eclipse and install it like that.

Comment: I am trying to download Eclipse Neon from official site. Hope it is the one i should download. I am not trying to download extensions seperately. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could resolve the issue.

1. Delete all the files which are already on the system in users folder related to eclipse.
2. Delete workspace if any. (Save projects seperately)
3. Try installing the eclipse from the official site. Try not to go for the online installers. Install full software

The Software installation will be succesful

Comment: Simply extract the zip file to a location of your choice and pin the included `eclipse.exe` to the start menu

Answer (score 4):

I came across an error code 1002 too as well.  The problem appears to be caused by the online resource it is trying to contact.  The solution resolved itself after waiting a couple hours.  I post this because I was seeing similar complaints elsewhere and wanted to spread knowledge of this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I will share my experience with this problem.

1. Started getting **Error 1002**
2. Downloaded and installed the latest JDK SE version.
3. Stopped getting **Error 1002**, but started getting **Error 4**
4. Downloaded and installed the latest JRE version.
5. Did not help, kept getting **Error 4**
6. Stopped the installer, deleted all the folders created by it in the pertinent folder (in my case it was *C:\Users\Me* )
7. Did not help again.
8. Took a nap (approx. 15-20 minutes)
9. Repeated **6.** (deleting all which the installer created)
10. Tried to install it again and **it worked** (although it was constantly warning me about the slowness of the installation process and the slow progress of the artifacts' download)

**Bottom line:** I guess it is a matter of time. You'll need to wait and, in the meantime, you can update your JDK and JRE.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was with my `wifi` connection:

> when i switched from my DSL wifi connection to a hotspot from my mobile using 4G connection, every thing worked well.