# Getting error while installing Eclipse 2020-R2

Tags: eclipse

I recently downloaded Eclipse 2020-R2 installer.  I was able to install successfully couple of days ago.  My computer crashed and had to reinstall OS.  Since then I have been unable to install same installer of Eclipse.  I am getting  Following error:

[image]

```
[2021-01-08 09:34:04] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-12/202012161000
[2021-01-08 09:34:04] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
[2021-01-08 09:34:06] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository code=1002 Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-12/202012161000.
org.tukaani.xz.XZFormatException: Input is not in the XZ format
  at org.tukaani.xz.common.DecoderUtil.decodeStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
  at org.tukaani.xz.SingleXZInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at org.tukaani.xz.SingleXZInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at org.tukaani.xz.XZInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at org.tukaani.xz.XZInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at org.tukaani.xz.XZInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at org.tukaani.xz.XZInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.XZedSimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(XZedSimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:82)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:63)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:775)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectUtil.java:119)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:423)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:214)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager$Metadata.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:495)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:110)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:105)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$RepositoryLoader$Worker.perform(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:1578)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.WorkerPool$Worker.run(WorkerPool.java:434)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)

[2021-01-08 09:34:06]
```

Comment: There is no Eclipse 2020-R2. According to the log it is the current release Eclipse 2020-12. It might be an temporary outage (even if it doesn't look like it according to [`eclipsestatus.io`](https://www.eclipsestatus.io/)). Are you behind a proxy? Can you open the website [`http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-12/202012161000`](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-12/202012161000) in a web browser?

Comment: Thanks for correcting the release version.  I am using this installer in my personal computer, without any proxies.  Also, I able to access https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-12/202012161000/

Comment: Does in the menu in the upper right _Bundles Pools..._ hitting the _Clear Cache..._ button help? Otherwise, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/41674861